# focus on input in webrowser object windows form app

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am developing win form app which includes specially made website with form. I am using int web browser object, in that I have problem.

I want to focus on specific input field after app is run.

HTML code :

```
<button id="btn">Ok</button><input id="txt">
```

In my app I have code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@"c:\test\test.htm");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txt").Focus();//Error here
    }
```

And  there I get `System.NullReferenceException`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting such error because, the specified control is not yet rendered in the DOM at the time of access. So what you need to do is, Trigger the event after the page fully loaded.  for this you can make use of `DocumentComplete Event` of the `WebBrowser` control as like the following:

```
private void DoComplete(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txt").Focus();
}
```

Reference : [WebBrowserControl-DocumentComplete Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)